# Java application server recommendations (Glassfish vs TomcatEE vs Wildfly)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, glassfish

I am currently starting a new project for a client, its a simple client-server POS terminal for  retail. I know we will need Java EE for this, the question now is which application server to implement it on. I have narrowed down my search to Glassfish, TomcatEE, Wildfly and maybe SpringBoot. However after searching for a few days I am more confused then when I started, here is some information I have gathered on the choices.

Tomcat:

- Lightweight and fast
- Most widely used

- Not meant for EE, is built as a web-app server.
- Not officially EE compatible.

Glassfish:

- Stable and well documented.
- Fully featured and certified Java EE app-server.
- Developed by oracle themselves.

- Steep learning curve
- Huge in size

Wildfly:

- Made by redHat, good quality, features built specifically for enterprise.
- Easy server configuration (single XML file)

- Slower? (from what i read)

Spring:

- Entire framework of program + application server in one.
- Very fast

- Steep learning curve

So my question is what do you all use for your JavaEE application servers? any Recommendations?

Many Many thanks in advance for any answers.